# Как сравнить 2 разных enum

Tags: c#, enum

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = AllowedNums.One;
        var b = Nums.Two;

        if (a.HasFlag(b))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Работает");
        }

    }
}
public enum AllowedNums
{
    One,
    Two
}
public enum Nums
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

Вот это вызывает ошибку. Говорит, что не совпадают типы, что логично. Мне пришло в голову несколько идей как это исправить, а именно: с помощью switch case и с помощью ToString() (в if), но мне кажутся эти пути не красивыми. Их так и хочется удалить и сидеть вечерами думать о том, как их исправить.

Comment: Не заводите одинаковые enum, они придуманы для того чтобы быть уникальными. В Delphi, я бы сказал вам сделать или `allowedNums = set of Nums и AllowedNums = [One, Two]`, либо ввести нормальные свойства `Spec: array [Nums] of record Allowed: Boolean; end;`

Comment: ```(int)a == (int)b;``` но это если у вас в Enum'ах все вот так как в примере, либо явное присвоение чисел элементам enum'a

Comment: Судя по наименованию `Allowed` у вас должен быть только один enum, и Allowed я бы указывал как перечисление: `var allowed = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Nums)).Cast<Nums>().Where(x => x != Nums.Tree);`

Comment: Чтобы работал `HasFlag()` разве не нужно дописать атрибут `[Flags]` к каждому `enum`? Но это конечно не относится к проблеме из вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по наименованию `Allowed` у вас должен быть только один enum, а Allowed я бы указывал как IEnumerable/Array/IList:

```
var allowed = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Nums)).Cast<Nums>().Where(x => x != Nums.Tree);
```

Или сформировать практически как угодно через yield если linq-выражение в `.Where` получается неочевидным и запутанным:

```
public IEnumerable<Nums> GetAllowed()
{
    yield return Nums.One;
    yield return Nums.Two;
}
```

А проверка соответственно будет тривиальной:

```
public bool IsAllowed(IEnumerable<Nums> allowed, Nums num)
{
    return allowed.Any(x => x == num);
}
```

Как-то так в итоге:

```
var allowed = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Nums)).Cast<Nums>().Where(x => x != Nums.Tree);

IsAllowed(allowed, Nums.One).Dump();
IsAllowed(allowed, Nums.Two).Dump();
IsAllowed(allowed, Nums.Tree).Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Есть вариант с расширением через сравнение интов

Добавьте класс

```cs
public static class AllowedNumsExtensions
{
    public static bool SameValue(this AllowedNums a, Nums b)
    {
        return (int)a == (int)b;
    }
}
```

Тогда можно вот так

```cs
if (a.SameValue(b))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Работает");
}
```

Comment: Это сработает, но тогда можно запихивать любые enum'ы, например, сравнивать дни недели и планеты солнечной системы. Я бы предпочёл в данной задаче ориентироваться на семантику: нужно проверить, что значение входит в конкретный enum и смысла плодить дубликаты enum'ов я не вижу.

Comment: @AK оно же строго привязано к типу, разве нет?

Comment: Верно, строго привязано к двум конкретным типам енумов, но семантически это совершенно разные типы. Я раньше и сам не обращал большого внимания на семантику, поэтому понимаю, что вполне возможно, что если речь идёт только о практическом аспекте "надо, чтобы работало" то это вполне рабочее решение.

Comment: @AK все верно, здесь уже ответственность разработчика. Вообще в вопросе он хочет странного. Для того чтобы узнать, присутствует ли значение из одного массива в другом массиве, не следует использовать `enum`, так как это фактически использование перечисления не по назначению. Собственно из миссюза проблема и вырастает. Я всего-лишь показал, как этот миссюз сделать немного безопаснее с точки зрения разработки.